# I wish to show and hide 1 or 2 drop down menus from another drop down selection

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I have code that when a item is selected in a drop down menu another drop down menu appears. However, individually it works but as soon as it involves 2 menus the code appears to conflict.
This is what I wish to do: 
When selecting 'Delivery', 'Time' drop down appears.
When selecting 'Collection', 'Number_of_parcels' drop down appears.
When selecting 'Collection_and_Delivery', both should appear.

Any help would be appreciated.

My code is below:

```
 function show(aval) {
    if (aval == "Collection" || aval == "Collection_and_Delivery") {
    hiddenDiv.style.display='inline-block';
    Form.fileURL.focus();
    } 
    else{
    hiddenDiv.style.display='none';
    }
 }

 function show(aval) {
    if (aval == "Delivery" || aval == "Collection_and_Delivery") {
    hiddenNo.style.display='inline-block';
    Form.fileURL.focus();
    } 
    else{
    hiddenNo.style.display='none';
    }
 }

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="form1" id="ff" method="post" action="http://www.xxxxxx.com/cgi-bin/form10.pl" onsubmit="myButton.disabled = true; return true;" target="_blank">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th align="left" colspan="3"> <select name="Collection_Delivery" id="Collection_Delivery" onchange="java_script_:show(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
        <option value="">-</option>
        <option value="Delivery">Delivery</option>
        <option value="Collection">Collection</option>
        <option value="Collection_and_Delivery">Collection &amp Delivery</option>
      </select>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <div id="hiddenDiv" style="display:none">
        <select name="Number_of_parcels" id="Number_of_parcels">
          <option value="z" selected="selected">No. of Parcels</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <div id="hiddenNo" style="display:none">
        <select name="Time" id="Time" onChange="selection()">
          <option value="x" selected="selected">Time</option>
          <option value="24hours">24 Hours</option>
          <option value="Next_day_9am">Next Day 9am</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are re-writting the show function declaring other show function.

I fixed the code and I did this:

```
function show(aval) {
  var showCollection = (aval === "Collection"|| aval === "Collection_and_Delivery");
  var showDelivery = (aval === "Delivery"|| aval === "Collection_and_Delivery");

  hiddenDiv.style.display= showCollection ? "inline-block" : "none";
  hiddenNo.style.display= showDelivery ? "inline-block" : "none";

  //Form.fileURL.focus();
}
```

I recommend you these links, if you want to start learning javascript:

- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions

Comment: That has solved the problem - thank you for your time and expertise. Your advice and links are noted.

Comment: I am now adding a similar drop down menu, they work correctly individually but they conflict and affect each other. How do I discern between the two?

Comment: Sorted. Just changed the second one to show1(aval).